# Mimic TouchCursor movements on Mac

Tags: keyboard

I'm using OS X Lion.

I'm a PC user and just recently tried out using a Mac.  I'm used to installing a handy app in Windows named [**TouchCursor**](http://touchcursor.sourceforge.net).  It allows me not to release my fingers in the "**home**" keys of the keyboard, which helps increase productivity (IMHO) because I don't need to reach out for the arrow keys anymore.

In Vim, the standard for the left, right, up and down is the H, L, K, and J keys.  I mimic it in Windows through TouchCursor by just adding the Spacebar (holding it down) + either H, L, K and J, depending on the direction I choose.  I made it universal, not only using Vim, but used it every time I navigate Windows, work with MS Office and other apps.

Is **[KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/index.html.en)** able to this just like I used to do it in TouchCursor?  Currently I have downloaded it and would be experimenting and see how it goes.  I just needed to post this question assuming someone might have experience solving this.

Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

I use both programs, and they are quite similar in spirit, but different in detail.  What I find works well for me in KeyRemap4MacBook is to turn on "normal mode" (I think that's what it is called).  I tap my Command key, then I can use vi-like keys, then I tap Command again (or use `i`).

Another useful thing is "simultaneous vi mode" (I think that's what it is called).  I press and hold `s` and `d` simultaneously, and while holding them I can use vi keys.  Quite similar to TouchCursor, except not with the space bar.

I wish there were programs that are more similar than these two, but I think this is currently where we are at.

Comment: (I realize the answer is coming a bit late.)

Comment: That's just fine. I'm currently playing with KeyRemap and it's Vim like settings. I was so used to TouchCursor back then that I can't go on without it. Even the author of the KeyRemap itself is giving me a custom settings to mimic the TouchCursor movements.

Comment: Cool!  I'd be interested in something similar to simultaneous vi mode, except with the space bar instead of `s` and `d`.  What do those custom settings look like?

Comment: Here's the private XML: https://www.dropbox.com/s/seykj7poubqgou6/private.xml.      The only thing I notice is that there's some delay in the Spacebar keyup event that when you type too fast it doesn't seem to work.  I mean, the Spacebar key can't catch up with your typing that you think that it doesn' work.  I usually end up with words "joined/sticked" together. Ifyou know whatI mean as I'mtyping this. :D